# Exception render symfony html error page instead of JSON response

Tags: json, symfony, exception, jwt

I have an application running with `Symfony5` and `ApiPlatform` using `JWT` in which I want some user not to be able to log in under some condition

So I have a listener `LoginListener` as follow:

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(AuthenticationSuccessEvent $event)
{
        $user = $event->getUser();
        if ($user->someCondition) {               
          throw new MyAccessDeniedException(json_encode('Ce compte n\'est plus actif.'));
        }
}
```

The exception class used is only that :

```
<?php

namespace App\Exception;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

class MyAccessDeniedException extends AccessDeniedException
{
}
```

I use this exception to throw a 403 pretty often in different cases, including in some other listeners.

The issue here is that, instead of returning an exception under json format, easily usable by the frontend, it returns an html page exception from symfony.

For example this is the kind of issue I'm trying to return, istead of the HTML :

```
"@context":"\/contexts\/Error","@type":"hydra:Error","hydra:title":"An error occurred","hydra:description":"Some error message","trace":[{"namespace":"","short_class":"","class":"",.....}
```

Does anyone knows why, on this particular exception the render of the exception turn out to be HTML and not JSON ? And if there is a workaround to this issue ?

Thanks !

Comment: Are you running in dev mode or prod? If you're in dev mode with the debug bar enabled then I think Symfony renders errors as HTMLs. In prod mode they should be returned as JSON.

Comment: Sorrry for the late response, I'm in dev, but have multiple exceptions triggered like that one, (exact same excpetions) that render properly in json compared to this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I couldn't figure out why HTML was returned, as this same exceptions triggered at other places do return the expected JSON, I tried to fire other exceptions like `badRequestException()`
It worked for me, it does not resolve the issue but is an acceptable fix to it in my case

Answer (score 1):

You can perform response by Listener [here I wrote article how it carried out](https://medium.com/@mukhiddin-jumaniyazov/symfony-custom-error-exception-response-fee4d51c29bf)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create an `AccessDeniedHandler`. See [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_denied_handler.html#customize-the-forbidden-response)

You can create your response with something like :

```php
return new JsonResponse($event->getMessage(), 403); 
// in your example, getMessage() returns your encoded error
```

Or if you have multiple and different `AccessDeniedException`, you can use an `AccessDeniedListener`. See [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_denied_handler.html#customizing-all-access-denied-responses)

Comment: Thanks for your comment and sorry for the late response, I tried return a JsonResponse() but it let the user connect and does not block him as I wanted. I found another fix, which get the work done